# List all Pipenv environments

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

How do you list all Pipenv environments like virtualenv's lsvirtualenv command?  The documentation does not say how. Thanks a lot to all for the help given. Cheers!

Comment: `lsvirtualenv` comes with `virtualenvwrapper` which is a utility for managing multiple virtualenvs. It does not list virtualenvs not managed through this wrapper (which centralizes the where the venvs are created).  While there is no equivalent to `virtualenvwrapper` (e.g. `Pipenvwrapper`) `Pipenv` does respect `WORKON_HOME` so should also provision `venv`s in the same directory so `lsvirtualenv` would also list those `venv`s.

Answer (score 23):

Why not simply looking for existing virtual environments?
To check where they are stored you can activate one virtual env and get its path:

```
$pipenv shell
$pipenv --venv
 > /path/to/existing_venvs/current_venv
ls /path/to/existing_venvs/
 > cython-pr4GGvfQ/  openCV-f4drK-E5/
```

I don't know if pipenv can store venvs in other places, but at least for me this is enough to know how many and which venvs I have.

Comment: Usually ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 10):

You can add the following alias to `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias pipenv-list='for venv in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/* ; do basename $venv; cat $venv/.project | sed "s/\(.*\)/\t\1\n/" ; done'
```

This will list all the virtual environments and the corresponding project (source) folder like:

```
$ pipenv-list
<PIPENV>
    <PROJECT_HOME_DIR>
[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

As AChampion [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904300/list-all-pipenv-environments#comment90759498_51904300), pipenv has no lsvirtualenv or similar functions.

The creator of pipenv, Kenneth Reitz, told [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/535#issuecomment-366444728) that is not planned to implement anything of the sort, and that people should rely in other tools like [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew).

I've tried pew and [pipes](https://github.com/gtalarico/pipenv-pipes) and both are good tools, but not the exact tools I was looking for my workflow, so for my personal use I built [pipenvwrapper](https://github.com/Peibolvig/pipenvwrapper) using the base code of virtualenvwrapper.

Some of the supported functions of pipenvwrapper are: workon, **lsvirtualenv**, cdproject, cdvirtualenv, cdsitepackages, mkproject and rmvirtualenv.

Check if any of those 3 tools fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, since I don't know a way to list all my virtual environments using any `pipenv` option, what I do is list the folder where all the virtual environments are.

In **Ubuntu** by default, `pipenv` creates a folder in `$HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs/` with the name of the virtual env, then listing that folder I have a list of all my environments.

To make life easier, I have created an alias to perform this operation.

Comment: I was looking for this functionality too which unfortunately does not exist. Apart from manually checking as posted above, a code editor like VSCode will keep track of installed environments in its list of available interpreters - if that helps.